# ce n’est pas pour autant

Tags: adverbes

https://www.journaldequebec.com/2020/09/09/coree-du-sud-les-tatoueurs-demandent-la-legalisation-de-leur-profession

En lisant cet article, je suis tombé sur la phrase "ce n’est pas pour autant que" à deux reprises et je peine à la comprendre. Et ce bien que l'algorithme m'ait recommandé de jeter un coup d'oeil sur [The phrase "pour autant"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/the-phrase-pour-autant)

Voici donc ce dont je parle:

> Comme partout dans le monde, les tatouages sont à la mode en Corée du Sud, popularisés par des vedettes de la K-pop, des sportifs et autres célébrités, mais ce n’est pas pour autant que la législation a évolué.

...

> Mais, ce n’est pas pour autant qu’il a pignon sur rue. Aucune enseigne ne signale son studio de tatouage, situé dans le centre de Séoul.

Je vous prie par conséquent de m'en éclairer le sens, soit en français, soit en anglais.

Answer (score 4):

L'expression "ce n'est pas pour autant que" signifie, si l'on paraphrase, "contrairement à ce qu'on pourrait penser/déduire/attendre/espérer de cette situation, cela n'implique pas forcément que".

Donc, dans ce passage:

> Comme partout dans le monde, les tatouages sont à la mode en Corée du Sud, popularisés par des vedettes de la K-pop, des sportifs et autres célébrités, mais ce n’est pas pour autant que la législation a évolué.

Cela signifie que bien que les tatouages soient à la mode et populaires, la législation n'a pas évolué comme on aurait pu s'y attendre.

> Mais, ce n’est pas pour autant qu’il a pignon sur rue. Aucune enseigne ne signale son studio de tatouage, situé dans le centre de Séoul.

Là, sans doute la phrase ou paragraphe précédents donnaient une indication sur ce tatoueur (par exemple, qu'il est renommé, ou a beaucoup de clients). En dépit de cela, et contrairement à ce qu'on aurait pu attendre, cela n'a pas eu pour conséquence qu'il ait pignon sur rue (et il n'a pas pignon sur rue).

Comment: By the way, what would be the English translation for "ce n'est pas pour autant"? It is very commonly used in France.